# Django Leaflet: Add form fields for latitude and longitude

Tags: django, django-admin, geodjango, django-leaflet

I am using the `django-leaflet` package to display the map in the django admin for a `PointField`. However, I wanted to put fields so that it would be possible to write the latitude and longitude, as an alternative to selecting the point on the map.

How can I add these fields to the form?

Note: the Django Map Widgets package has the ability to insert coordinates, but I don't want to use it because it requires a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a model form with 2 new fields such as lat, lng. Then you can validate if point selected in the map or lat, lng fields are filled.

```
class PointEntryOrSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lat = forms.FloatField(required=False, label='Latitude')
    lng = forms.FloatField(required=False, label='Longtitude')

    class Meta:
        widgets = {'geom': LeafletWidget()}
        model = YourModel
        exclude = ['', ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        geom = self.initial.get("geom", None)
        if isinstance(geom, Point):
            self.initial["lng"], self.initial["lat"] = geom.tuple

    def clean(self):
        data = super().clean()
        if set(self.changed_data)>={"lat","lng"}:
            lat, lng = data.pop("lat", None), data.pop("lng", None)
            data["geom"] = Point(lng, lat, srid=4326)
    
        if not (data["geom"] or (data["lat"] and data["lng"])):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                {"geom": "No coordinates."})
        return data

@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin( LeafletGeoAdmin):
    form = PointEntryOrSelectForm
```